# Как сделать относительную анимацию поворота объекта unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всем доброго времени суток! 
Делаю анимацию двери. Телу двери добавил пустого родителя на который навесил анимации поворота. И при повороте родителя тело благополучно поворачивалось и все работало как надо. Но оно все работало, пока у родителя изначально rotation был нулевой, а как только я его хотел как-то повернуть, анимация сначала резко поворачивала родителя до нулевого rotation, а потом уже медленно поворачивалась. Это происходит потому, что у меня анимация в глобальных координатах. Тогда я этому родителю(который с анимацией) добавил нового пустого родителя и уже его попытался развернуть. Но теперь анимация совсем сломалась: объект уже не поворачивался а менял форму  и крутился вокруг своей оси.
Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему
**PS**
В интернете искал, но ничего полезного не нашел.

Comment: Пробовал нажать галочку Apply Root Motion в инспекторе аниматора?

Comment: Пробовал, результат не поменялся

Comment: На ум пока приходит убрать анимацию и сделать открытие/закрытие двери с помощью кода, но как по мне это совсем костыльный вариант.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, у нас есть вот такая иерархия:

```
MainParent(пустой объект)
--Parent(анимация)
----body(тело двери)
```

**MainParent не должен быть пустым объектом, он должен быть кубом**, чтобы его дети могли как бы в нем 'поместится'. Тогда тело двери работает нормально и не скукоживается.
Самое интересное, что это решение пришло мне в голову совершенно случайно